# How to efficiently close two goroutines?

Tags: go

I'm using two concurrent goroutines to copy stdin/stdout from my terminal to a net.Conn target. For some reason, I can't manage to completely stop the two go routines without getting a panic error (for trying to close a closed connection). This is my code:

```
func interact(c net.Conn, sessionMap map[int]net.Conn) {
    quit := make(chan bool) //the channel to quit

    copy := func(r io.ReadCloser, w io.WriteCloser) {
        defer func() {
            r.Close()
            w.Close()
            close(quit) //this is how i'm trying to close it
        }()

        _, err := io.Copy(w, r)

        if err != nil {
            //
        }

    }

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                return
            default:
                copy(c, os.Stdout)
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                return
            default:
                copy(os.Stdin, c)
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

This errors as `panic: close of closed channel`

I want to terminate the two go routines, and then normally proceed to another function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling `copy` twice (also don't use `copy`, since it's a bultin function), and each one closes the same channel. You're checking `quit` before it could be closed, since you call `copy` after. You generally don't want to close stdin, and probably not stdout either. Why is `copy` called in a for loop at all, since once it's done, it's done?

Comment: Hi I dont understand, if you have code examples they will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `close` on a channel more than once, there's no reason to call `copy` in a for loop, since it can only operate one time, and you're copying in the wrong direction, writing to stdin and reading from stdout.

Simply asking how to quit 2 goroutines is simple, but that's not the only thing you need to do here. Since `io.Copy` is blocking, you don't need the extra synchronization to determine when the call is complete. This lets you simplify the code significantly, which will make it a lot easier to reason about.

```
func interact(c net.Conn) {
    go func() {
        // You want to close this outside the goroutine if you
        // expect to send data back over a half-closed connection
        defer c.Close()

        // Optionally close stdout here if you need to signal the
        // end of the stream in a pipeline.
        defer os.Stdout.Close()

        _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, c)
        if err != nil {
            //
        }
    }()

    _, err := io.Copy(c, os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        //
    }
}
```

Also note that you may not be able to break out of the `io.Copy` from stdin, so you can't expect the `interact` function to return. Manually doing the `io.Copy` in the function body and checking for a half-closed connection on every loop may be a good idea, then you can break out sooner and ensure that you fully close the `net.Conn`.

Comment: Thank you for the simplification, implementing it right now - about your latter paragraph: care to give an example code? I think this is the core solution to a problem I've been struggling with for the last week!

Comment: Actually, if you know that the `net.Conn` is never expecting data back over a half-closed connection, put the `c.Close` in the goroutine, and that should suffice.

Comment: You amazed me with this solution. multiple graditudes.
I'm trying to call another function (function B) from witin the Stdin error if statement - if err !=nil { B()} ...  - Somehow, a log.Print from function B shows up, but stuff like fmt.Print dont. - any idea why its acting this way?

Comment: @tatoe: well, you've closed Stdout, so you can no longer write to stdout. If you want to continue writing to stdout, then don't close it.

Comment: That has solved me a full weeks work. I have idea how to thank you more!

Answer (score 0):

Also could be like this

```
 func scanReader(quit chan int, r io.Reader) chan string {
          line := make(chan string)
           go func(quit chan int) {
                    defer close(line)
                    scan := bufio.NewScanner(r)
                    for scan.Scan() {
                    select {
                       case <- quit:
                          return
                       default:
                          s := scan.Text()
                          line <- s
                    }
                    }
                }(quit)
               return line
    }

            stdIn := scanReader(quit, os.Stdin) 
            conIn := scanReader(quit, c) 
        for {
            select {
                    case <-quit:
                        return
                    case l <- stdIn:
                        _, e := fmt.Fprintf(c, l)
                        if e != nil {
                           quit <- 1
                           return
                        }
                    case l <- conIn:
                        fmt.Println(l)
                    }
        }
```